# In Idris, can IO happen in any universe?

Tags: io, idris, universe

That's my question. Idris has a cumulative universe hierarchy where the universe is inferred by the compiler. Does the use of `dosomethingreal : IO` imply the lowest universe in the hierarchy? Is `IO : Type` and never `IO : Type 1`? Or can I have IO actions in any universe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can. For example, the type `Type -> Type` is in a higher universe than the argument type. So `Type -> Type` is definitely not in the lowest universe and neither is `IO (Type -> Type)`, but

```
test : IO (Type -> Type)
test = return List
```

runs fine.